# Get input faster in c++

Tags: c++, input, output

I have made a program that takes 1.01 seconds and time limit is 1 second . So i need way to increase the speed of input or output .

I need to take two words{(non space) can be upper . lower , numbers} as input , what is the fastest way to do it . I will not put my code here as it is a ongoing contest and  i want explanation in little simple way .

This is the code, i need better way to input those two words . any other suggestions are welcomed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string a, b;
    int number_cases=0,i,j,count=0;
    cin>>number_cases;
    while(number_cases!=0)
    {
        cin>>a;
        cin>>b;
        for(i=0;i<a.size();i++) {
            for(j=0;j<b.size();j++) {
                if(a[i]==b[j]) {
                    count++;
                    b[j]='#';
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        cout<<count<<endl;
        count=0;
        --number_cases;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough info to diagnose something.. sorry. "Enable optimizations, do it in a multi-core fashion".. these are all too broad suggestions.

Comment: You need to greatly expand this describing what your currently doing, as it stands its unanswerable

Comment: This is too vague for anyone to provide a helpful answer. Without code, identifying performance issues is impossible. Voting to close.

Comment: You need to greatly expand on the number of searches you do to get your lazy-web answers, instead! I'm not even linking my own relevant answers here

Comment: Edited .  @ david , @ dvnrrs @sehe

Comment: Please condense the relevant code into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) and _include it in your question_. Right now the content on the site you provided is not visible to the public. If it disappears after your question has been answered the value of it and any answers can drop significantly.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/kM4SGyKK

Comment: @SanchitBansal I think this question will be better for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @SanchitBansal Have you tested your code? What did you do to test it? Where was the performance bottleneck? How did you determine what the bottleneck was? Have you looked at the assembly language? These are the things a software engineer would do. Running straight to stack overflow to ask someone else to provide you the answer is what a future MacDonalds employee would do. Which do you want to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a minimal speedup, replacing the c++ STL input/output functions with the older C functions will do the trick.

```
cout<<count<<endl;
```

can be

```
printf("%i\n",count);
```

C++ stream operators are controversial, but generally speaking they are more robust, while C input/output operations are faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your input isn't what's taking the time.

Your character comparisons are nested loop! This is O(n.m) complexity and will perform really badly for large strings. Consider two strings of 1024 characters.

If you described the problem, we might give you hints, but this is *your* competition entry.

Suffice it to say, input is most likely *not* your worry.